# Xamarin - Camera class or object prevents my phone camera from working

Tags: xamarin

I have written an app that switch on the Flashlight. My only issue is that every time i open my app, my phone camera option stops working - that is i can't open my camera anymore. The camera starts working only if i kill my application. Here is my code :

```
public static Camera camera = null;
```

I call TurnCameraOn() in my ON button and TurnCameraOff in my OFF button.

```
private void TurnCameraOn()
        {
            if (CameraAvailable() == true)
            {
                if (camera == null)
                    camera = Camera.Open();

                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
                parameters.FlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch;

                camera.SetParameters(parameters);
                Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture mPreviewTexture = new Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture(0);

                camera.SetPreviewTexture(mPreviewTexture);
                camera.StartPreview();

                cameraFlashLightOnThread = true;
            }
        }

        private void TurnCameraOff()
        {
            if (CameraAvailable() == true)
            {
                if (camera == null)
                    camera = Camera.Open();

                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();

                parameters.FlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOff;

                camera.SetParameters(parameters);
                camera.StopPreview();

                cameraFlashLightOnThread = false;
            }
        }

        private bool CameraAvailable()
        {
            bool availale = true;

            if (PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureCamera) == false)
            {
                availale = false;
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No back-facing camera available", ToastLength.Long);
            }

            if (PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureCameraFlash) == false)
            {
                availale = false;

                Toast.MakeText(this, "No camera flash available", ToastLength.Long);
            }

            return availale;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is holding a reference to the camera and never releasing it. when you turn the LED/flash off, dispose of your camera instance so the camera may be used by other apps.

Something like:

```
private void TurnCameraOn()
{
    if (CameraAvailable())
    {
        camera = camera ?? Camera.Open();
        using (var parameters = camera.GetParameters())
        {
            parameters.FlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch;
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture mPreviewTexture = new Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture(0);
            camera.SetPreviewTexture(mPreviewTexture);
            camera.StartPreview();
        }
        cameraFlashLightOnThread = true;
    }
}

private void TurnCameraOff()
{
    if (CameraAvailable())
    {
        camera = camera ?? Camera.Open();
        using (var parameters = camera.GetParameters())
        {
            parameters.FlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOff;
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            camera.StopPreview();
            camera.Dispose();
            camera = null;
        }
        cameraFlashLightOnThread = false;
    }
}
```

FYI: Your `Toast` statements are missing `.Show()` and thus would never been shown to the user.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly fine. But i replaced .Dispose()  with .release ()(), because once i dispose the camera object, i cant instantiate it again by using this code : camera = camera ?? Camera.Open(); . I get an error message that says camera can't be accessed.